# Steps to install Ubuntu without shutting down winxp

Tags: 14.04

I have bootable USB with ubuntu 14.04. As my BIOS cannot change the priority of boot device. I need to start installation ubuntu, within logging winxp, by bootable USB in it. can i do it like that??

Thanks and regards,
shahas

Comment: Please tell us the bios version your system has. To my knowledge all have the option to change the boot order. Otherwise it would be  near -impossible- to install a new operating system. (or make/model of your system if you are not sure how to get the bios version)

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to change the boot priority.

Alternatives (both will -not- get you to a dual boot but to an installation inside Windows XP)

- virtualbox
- WUBI. Installer for WUBI is on the installation media

---

- Also possible: insert an empty unformatted hard disc into your system. If there is no operating system it could (some bios do) automatically ask for a DVD to boot from.

It is probably not possible to remove the active operating system.